Automatización de Envío Masivo de Reels en Instagram
¿Que es todo esto, en que consiste?
Este proyecto busca desarrollar un script en Python utilizando Selenium WebDriver para enviar de manera automatizada un reel específico en Instagram mediante mensajes directos. El objetivo es realizar este envío masivo a una cuenta particular, como por ejemplo para inundar la bandeja de entrada de un amigo, aunque también podría tener otros usos... o eso creo
Problemas ‍
Actualmente se detiene en la parte del reel y no completa el proceso. Necesito ayuda para solucionar este problema y finalizar la automatización correctamente.
Este es el código:
(Lo saque con ayuda de IA y mis conocimientos justos)
send_reel_by_dm(reel_url, recipient)
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Configuración del servicio Chrome y uso de tu perfil de Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/<TuUsuario>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/SeleniumProfile")
chrome_options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

# Configuración del servicio y el driver de Chrome
service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# URL del reel y cuenta destinataria
reel_url = "URL_DEL_REEL"
recipient = "USUARIO_DESTINATARIO"

# Función para enviar un reel por mensaje directo en Instagram
def send_reel_by_dm(reel_url, recipient):
    try:
        # Abrir Instagram
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(3)  # Esperar a que cargue la página

        # Iniciar sesión si no está iniciada (asumiendo que ya tienes la sesión iniciada)
        # Si necesitas iniciar sesión en cada ejecución, deberás modificar esta parte
        if "accounts/login" in driver.current_url:
            # Aquí deberías agregar el código para iniciar sesión automáticamente
            # Por ejemplo, llenar los campos de usuario y contraseña y hacer clic en 'Login'
            pass

        # Navegar al URL del reel
        driver.get(reel_url)
        time.sleep(5)  # Esperar a que cargue el reel

        # Bucle para enviar el reel múltiples veces
        for i in range(100):  # Cambia el número 100 por la cantidad de veces que desees enviar el reel
            # Hacer clic en el botón de enviar por mensaje directo
            send_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='wpO6b']")))
            send_button.click()

            # Esperar a que aparezca el campo de destinatario y escribir el nombre del destinatario
            recipient_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='dialog']//input[@name='queryBox']")))
            recipient_input.send_keys(recipient)
            time.sleep(2)  # Esperar a que aparezca la lista de sugerencias

            # Seleccionar al destinatario de la lista de sugerencias
            recipient_select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='dialog']//div[@class='                    Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         vwCYk                                        bZAIg']")))
            recipient_select.click()

            # Hacer clic en el botón de enviar
            final_send_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Send')]")))
            final_send_button.click()

            print(f"Reel enviado {i+1} veces a {recipient} por mensaje directo.")
            time.sleep(5)  # Esperar un tiempo antes de enviar el siguiente reel (ajusta según sea necesario)

    finally:
        driver.quit()

# Ejecutar la función para enviar el reel por mensaje directo en bucle
send_reel_by_dm(reel_url, recipient)


Básicamente deseas inundar los DMs de alguien? Instagram terminará la cuenta en cuanto lo hagas, además, no es de ninguna manera gracioso, ni puede ser destinado a un "buen" (entre 1 millón de comillas) uso por otra gente.

Básicamente, lo que no entiendo es por qué hay tanta censura en temas como el hacking o el spam, incluso cuando se trata de scripts que se utilizan en entornos controlados. Siempre hay muy poca información al respecto. Creo que la información que busco se encuentra en esa parte oculta de Internet, la famosa deep-dark web, pero los enlaces también son difíciles de encontrar...
